# Get gradle.properties file from Gradle custom plugin

Tags: gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I'm developing a Gradle plugin and I need to read and write to `gradle.properties` project file. I have tried this:

```
@TaskAction
public void myAction() {
     Properties properties = new Properties();
        try {
            properties.load(new FileInputStream(getProject().file("gradle.properties")));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

But I get `FileNotFoundException`. How can I get the file?

Comment: Does `gradle.properties` file exist before the first time the task is run?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the error. [Gradle API Documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Project.html) says that `.file(Object path)` method in `Project` class:

> Resolves a file path relative to the project directory of this
>   project.

My `gradle.properties` file was in root project, instead of in the module where plugin is applied.